# Creating a Public SPARQL endpoint with Fuseki: no sparql.html file

Tags: apache, sparql, fuseki

I am trying to create a public SPARQL endpoint. I found [this](http://csarven.ca/how-to-create-a-linked-data-site#public-sparql-endpoint) guide online which recommends making a reverse proxy and adding three lines of rewrite code to my Apache configuration. The lines I need to add are as follows:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/sparql$ /usr/lib/fuseki/pages/sparql.html [L]
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=
> RewriteRule . http://localhost:3030/dataset/query [P]
> ```

However one of these lines refers to a query form `sparql.html` that should be stored in the Fuseki folder downloaded by the user (`/usr/lib/fuseki/pages/sparql.html`). But I can't find this in the folder for the version of Fuseki that I downloaded, the latest version. Can I find this query form elsewhere or is there another way of doing it.

Comment: Your question will get better answers if you show what code you have and what research you have done to find out the root cause of the problem. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Dear M. le Rutte I've edited the question in order to make it clearer what I'm looking for. I've posted the code I have. The research I've done was searching on google with appropriate keywords. I couldn't find the answer that way so I was hoping stack exchange might help. If you have any further suggestions I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: The article was published in 2011, obviously, the author mean Fuseki 1. Probably you could replace `sparql.html` with `webapp/dataset.html` for Fuseki2. [This](https://pastebin.com/f6UzNuCt) is a part of my Nginx config.

Comment: Yes - dataset.html is the nearest equivalent.  You will need to expose the JS and CSS as well.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/jena/tree/master/jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-basic/sparqler/pages contains the pages from sparql.org which is more like Fuseki1 - sparql.org runs those pages with fuseki-basic which you can get from maven central.